# Не могу найти ошибку в синтаксисе sql

Tags: mysql, sql

```
ALTER TABLE hooptie
RENAME TO car_table,
CHANGE COLUMN mo model,
CHANGE COLUMN howmuch price,
ADD COLUMN car_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST,
ADD PRIMARY KEY(car_id),
ADD COLUMN VIN VARCHAR(16) AFTER car_id,
MODIFY COLUMN color AFTER model;

mysql ругается на ошибку в синтаксисе, но я не могу ее найти, буду благодарен, если без матов и минусометов скажите где ошибка.
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: CHANGE COLUMN должно задавать полную новую спецификацию. Для переименования поля используется RENAME COLUMN.

Comment: @Akina , Я пишу: `RENAME COLUMN mo TO model`, но все-равно вылетает ошибка